# Testing with cloud kit: having trouble removing test records

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, icloud

Okay, so I've been having trouble writing decent tests for cloud interactions. I have a project (voyage) that get's a record placed in cloud for testing, and that project gets a participant attached to it by reference (participant has it's own record too (crewMember)). Now during the teardown after the test I delete the voyage, and expected that to delete the crewMember record as well (reference is .DeleteSelf), but that never happens.

I now manually call to delete (with a dispatch_group to wait) at the end of the method, but it still is in the database after waiting concludes (which causes the test to fail the next time it runs). If the code below is not enough, I can add more or link to Github. My question is **why is dispatch group progressing without successfully deleting from the cloud, and why is crewMember's record not getting removed by either method (.DeleteSelf in reference or 'deleteRecordable' which works in most other instances)?**.

As for errors, I seem to get a lot of 'record changed' errors, although I'm not sure if it's being generated by this transaction in particular and I don't know why that would stop the deletion (why would it matter if the record changed; but also how is it getting changed after I've started to delete it?).

I added this at the end of the test:

```
    // Remove record for additional tests.
    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    crewMember.deleteFromCloud(database) {
        print("leaving dispatch group...")
        dispatch_group_leave(group) }
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

and the `deleteFromCloud` function looks like this:

```
/*
 * This method removes the instance conforming to Recordable from the cloud. Any preparation
 * or follow up required by an instance needs to be handled here. If possible use generic
 * function from CloudInteractor for implementation.
 */
func deleteFromCloud(database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (() -> ())? = nil) {
    let cloud = CloudInteractor()
    cloud.deleteRecordable(self, database: database, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

with `deleteRecordable` (which seems to be working fine in several other instances) looking like this:

```
/**
 * This method deletes any instance that conforms to recordable from the cloud. Has no checks or constraints 
 * before attempting removal.
 */
func deleteRecordable<T: Recordable>
    (instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase,     completionHandler: (() -> ())? = nil) {
    let recordID = instanceConformingToRecordable.recordID
print("deleting \(recordID)")   // <-- NOT SKIPPED
    database.deleteRecordWithID(recordID) { recordID, error in
print("deletion concluding...")    // <-- !! SKIPPED !!
        guard error == nil else {
print("d!snap")                    // <-- !! SKIPPED !!
            self.tempHandler =  self.deleteRecordable(instanceConformingToRecordable,
                                                 database: database,
                                                 completionHandler: completionHandler)
print("d!crackle :\(self.tempHandler)") // <-- !! SKIPPED !!
            CloudErrorHandling.handleError(error!, errorMethodSelector: #selector(self.runTempHandler))
print("d!pop")              // <-- !! SKIPPED !!
            return
        }
print("deletion had no errors: \(recordID)")  // <-- Never reached...
        if let handler = completionHandler { handler() }
    }
}
```